# Kindle Fire opening front camera by default while it should open the back camera

Tags: android, camera, android-camera, kindle-fire

I have this camera application which is working fine on almost all other devices except the Kindle Fire HDX 8.9

The problem is that when I open the camera inside the surface view I explicitly tell it to open the Back facing camera:

```
this.camera = Camera.open(Camera.CameraInfo.CAMERA_FACING_BACK);
```

But for some reason, on the Kindle Fire HDX, a user has reported that it is opening the front camera by default. Any ideas as to how to fix it?